# Area of the surface when the curve is revolved about the x-axis

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, area

Find the area of the surface generated when the given curve is revolved about the x-axis.
$y=2x+7$ on [0,4]

This is what I have :

$$S=\int_{a}^{b} 2π \left(f(x)\right)\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2} $$
$$S=\int_{0}^{4} 2π \left(2x+7\right)\sqrt{1+(2)^2} $$

$$2\pi[\left(x^2+7x\right)\sqrt{5}]_1^4$$
$$2\pi[(4^2+7(4))\sqrt{5}-(1^2+7(1))\sqrt{5}]$$
$$2\pi[(44)\sqrt{5}-(9)\sqrt{5}]$$
I don't know where to from here, is this the answer or can it be simplified even more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2 \pi (15 \sqrt{5} - 9 \sqrt{5}) =\pi * 2(15-9) \sqrt{5} =  12 \sqrt{5} \pi$

That's the result!

Regarding your calculation:
Is $\int_{0}^4 (2x+7)$ not equal to $[x^2+7x]_0^4$?

Remember the $dx$ in the integral!

Comment: what happens to the other $\sqrt{5}$?

Comment: can you show me where I made the mistake in my calculations?

Comment: mistake on the step from 3rd line to 4th line. You must integrate like this: $\int_0^4 2 \pi(2x+7) \sqrt{5}dx = [2 \pi(x^2+7x) \sqrt{5}]_0^4$.

Comment: ok then my answer changes drastically